# Debug an external process?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm working with a certain external server product which happens to be proprietary. However, I do have the ability to modify the server's startup scripts. What I'd like to do is essentially set debugging breakpoints in the custom module code which I'm writing so as to be able to fix a bug I'm experiencing in my code.

Is there a way to do this, integrating Eclipse with debugging an external process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that certain external server product is a Java server, you should be able to debug your code running in it through standard Java remote debugging.

In Eclipse, open the Debug configurations and add a new configuraion of type "Remote Java Application", and enter the hostname of the server and the port the remote debugger listens to.

In the server startup script, you may need to add an additional Java option to enable remote debugging for the JVM and specify the port. Something like this (excerpt from the JBoss startup config file):

```
# Sample JPDA settings for remote socket debugging
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
```

(address - 8787 in this case - is the port to connect to)